# Appending date to filename, but before file extension

Tags: bash

I need to append the current date to the end of a filename and currently use the following:

```
mv "$file" "${file}_$dateNow"
```

So if I have the file `Testfile1.xml` it will get changed to `Testfile1.xml230124`

What I want to do is place the date after the filename, but before the file extension, ie `Testfile1120324.xml`

How may I do this? The file extension will not always be `.xml`, could be anything of any length.

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Shouldn't that be `mv "${file}.${ext}" "${file}_$(date +%y%m%d).${ext}"`? :-) (with a small "y" in order for the year only to contain 2 characters)

Comment: bash can format dates without calling out to `date` -> `printf -v dateNow '%(%y%m%d)T'; echo "$dateNow"`

Comment: Try `mv "$file" "${file%.*}$dateNow.${file##*.}"`.

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Answer (score 1):

This solution works using `bash`'s [parmeter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) / [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) and and will place the date before multiple file extensions such as `tar.gz`:

```
mv "${file}" "${file%%.*}${dateNow}.${file#*.}"
# myfile.tar.gz -> myfile2023_01_24.tar.gz
```

The first part of this solution uses `${file%%.*}` to greedily match against the `.*` at the end of the variable and cuts out that match returning the difference.

The end part, `${file#*.}`, works in the opposite way by lazily matching against   the `*.` pattern at the beggining of the variable and returning the difference.

If for example you want to place the date before just the first extension you can do this:

```
mv "${file}" "${file%.*}${dateNow}.${file##*.}"
# google.com.txt -> google.com2023_01_24.txt
```

I am assuming you have properly set the `$dateNow` var, however if you haven't then you can use the `date` command to insert the date:

```
mv "${file}" "${file%%.*}$(date +'%Y_%m_%d').${file#*.}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
filename="example.txt"
extension="${filename##*.}"
filename="${filename%.*}"
new_filename="$filename-$(date +%Y%m%d).$extension"
mv "$filename.$extension" "$new_filename"
```

This command first saves the file extension to a variable called "extension" by using the parameter substitution pattern ${filename##*.}.
Then it saves the filename without the extension to a variable called "filename" by using the parameter substitution pattern ${filename%.*}.
Then it creates a new variable called "new_filename" that appends the current date to the filename before the extension by using the command date +%Y%m%d and concatenating it to the filename variable.
Finally, it uses the mv command to rename the original file to the new filename.

This command will append the current date formatted as YYYYMMDD to the file name before the extension, you can change the format of the date by changing the parameter on `date

Comment: Did you use ChatGPT to generate this answer?

Answer (score -1):

I would first put `$file` apart into everything before and after the extension:

```
if [[ $file =~ ^(.*)[.]([^./]*)$ ]]
then
  newname=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_$dateNow.${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
else
  newname=$file_$dateNow
fi
mv -n "$file" "$newname"
```

Note that this also handles cases such as when file contains `a.b/c.d` (extension is just `d`, not `b/c.d`)  and when file contains ' a.b/c` (no extension provided).

The `-n` catches the case that we accidentally already have a file named `$newname` in our directory.